# Totally weird PHP variable scope behaviour (also weird IDE behaviour) – can anyone make sense of this?

Tags: php, scope, phpstorm

I'm asking this question b/c a certain PHP (and IDE) behaviour confuses me, and I was wondering if anyone can make sense of it. If you are proficient in variable scope questions, then this question is for you!

So I have an index.php file in which at one point I define a variable called `$pageKat = "";` and later assign it a value based on certain conditions.

Then I `require` another php file from index.php called _actual-content.php.

```php
<?php # index.php

...

$pageKat = "";

...

if (...) {
    $pageKat = "foo";
}

...

require __DIR__ . '/_actual-content.php';
```

The first 11 lines of my _actual-content.php look like this:

```
<div id="theMan">

<header>
    <?php if ($GLOBALS["pageKat"] == "home") echo "<h1 class='h1Home'>"; ?>[REDACTED-HTML]<?php if ($pageKat == "home") echo "</h1>"; ?>
</header>

<nav class="headerMenu" aria-label="Haupt-Navigation">
    <ul>
        <?php generateMainMenu($pageKat); print_r($pageKat); ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The `[REDACTED-HTML]` part is there to make it all easier readable. There's really just plain static HTML there that generates a logo. It has nothing to do with the question at hand and I've redacted it to de-clutter the code block.

Now, as you can see, I am accessing $pageKat three times here (actually four times, if you count the debugging `print_r`).

Here's the weird part:

- In the first `<?php ... ?>` block, I'm using the $GLOBALS array to access pageKat (as one would expect is necessary). I first tried to access $pageKat, but that doesn't work, as $pageKat is not in the scope of _actual-content.php (again, as expected).
- In the second and third `<?php ... ?>` block, though, weirdly, I AM able to access $pageKat directly. The IDE (PhpStorm) marks it as "undefined" (with a red wavy line beneath it, again: as expected)... but it works. The `if` statement is processed correctly and the `</h1>` HTML is echoed if $pageKat is "home". The generateMainMenu() function is also called correctly and works like a charm, the print_r() dumps $pageKat's value... all fine.

So my question is: Why? Why does it work? (I tried checking whether you can access a global variable inside a scope "directly" after having accessed it once via $GLOBALS, but this does not seem to be in PHP specs.)

Again, I'm asking this question because I'm trying to wrap my head around how variable scope works, and this behaviour looks completely odd to me. I'm curious what the heck is going on, so if anyone can enlighten me, I'd be very thankful.

*(Please let's not have this question degenerate into a discussion about how bad global variables are. I'm a total noob and I know it, I've always loved global vars, and I will fight for their right to exist until my last breath. ;) This is not the point here.)*

Comment: A different file does not mean a different scope. If you define `$pageKat` in your index.php file and include `my _actual-content.php` below it, you can simply access it as it is in the same scope.

Comment: Read [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). _"This single scope spans included and required files as well."_ `$pageKat` _should_ be directly available in `_actual-content.php`. I imagine Storm is redlining it because it's just doing static analysis and applying best practice -- i.e., the code in the second file shouldn't just blindly assume that $pageKat has been defined.

Comment: @Siv: Please see my edit (sorry if it appears stepping over), and double-check if the require line is well placed as well as the index.php is as it is for the important parts. I've reverse engineered from your description, but was not sure where the require is placed. Also can you please elaborate why you expect the $pageKat to be unset? From your question I could (but might have missed that) not gather that information and given index.php is the entrypoint $pageKat _is_ global, later on requiring a different file should not change that unless done within a function with its own scope.

Comment: _The IDE (PhpStorm) marks it as "undefined"_: Not reproducible. PhpStorm marks the _Undefined function 'generateMainMenu'_ in inspections but every $pageKat and $GLOBALS["pageKat"] is fine. Add your PHP and IDE version to the question. It is also likely that you hide important details in your question, this could be another explanation.

Comment: Thanks guys, you really helped out. To go through the points:

@AlexHowansky: You were spot on. PhpStorm redlined it wrongly.I simply blindly trusted its "variable is undefined" warning without ever (EVER!) actually testing whether a marked variable is really defined or undefined. The fact that Storm said "that's undefined" was enough for me. As a matter of fact, this is where my belief is rooted in that included or required php files form a new scope.

Comment: @hakre: your edits were correct, you read my description correctly. FYI if still interested PhpStorm version is 2013.1.2 Build #PS-231.9011.38, and I am able to reproduce it. You can however click "add global" in the tooltip to tell PStorm that it's a global var and then it stops redlining it. I had expected PhpStorm to understand that b.php is included from a.php and deduce globals from that, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: So, time to close this. Sorry for such a stupid oversight. You would not believe how long I've lived with a wrong construct in my head due to a red wavy line.

I have learned this: Never blindly trust your IDE. :)

Comment: Don't close it, add this as **your** answer and accept it (take a moment until you can). I'll also add an answer showing the versions I've test with.

Comment: The "undefined variable" -- this depend son the corresponding inspection config. By default PhpStorm checks for variable in the **current file** only, hence the "undefined variable" warning. But after you enable an option in that inspection the IDE will take other/global files into the consideration.

Comment: On the screenshot in your answer -- use "More actions..." option -- it will list all applicable intentions/quick fixes. If you choose the right entry (should be the top one) and expand the submenu, you will see more actions. One of them will be to open the Settings/Preferences screen with that inspection selected, where you can configure it a bit. Give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: $pageKat actually is a global var and as such defined in the included .php, OP (me) simply assumed it wasn't because of the wavy red line by the IDE that marked it as "undefined". I'll show myself out.

- PhpStorm 2023.1.2 Build #PS-231.9011.38

---

For final clarification, here's a screenshot of what global variables in included files look like in PhpStorm 2023.1.2:

[image: Screenshot of PhpStorm 2023.1.2 marking a global variable in an included .php file as "undefined" and offering to "Add 'global [variable]'"]

(Disclaimer: Demonstrating here with a different global variable than the one mentioned in the original q.)

Additional info: Clicking "Add 'global $[variable]'" causes PhpStorm to add `global$[variable]` (w/o whitespace before $) to the beginning of the current file...

Comment: See how well this plays?

Comment: While I marked this (my own ) answer as correct (as it directly answers the question), I encourage anyone interested to also read @Skudd's reply for more insight into how PhpStorm reads/interprets variables in projects. They also offer a coding style solution that is not affected by this "shortcoming".

Answer (score 1):

As commented earlier, I was not able to reproduce it. For future reference, my setup:

- PhpStorm 2023.2 Build #PS-232.8660.205
- PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2023 07:10:21) (NTS)

This means: It is likely with your older PhpStorm 2023.1.2 Build #PS-231.9011.38 you still need to mark the variable as global.

Here a preview:

[image: $GLOBALS array with source locations]

Ctrl + Left Mouse Button (LMB) opens *Choose Declaration* pop-up menu. Both entries resolve to index.php locations:

1. to $pageKat = "";
2. to $pageKat = "foo";

[image: Type inference for global variable, here string]

Ctrl + Mouse Hover show type inference of the variable, it's a string. Ctrl + LMB resolves to $pageKat = ""; in index.php.

---

Full rundown:

```
$ cd ~/PhpstormProjects/hakre/sos/so76843156
$ cat composer.json
{
  "name": "sos/so76843156",
  "require": {
    "php": "8.2"
  },
  "extra": {
    "composer.json": {
      "offical": {
        "url": "https://getcomposer.org/schema.json",
        "refs": [
          {
            "The composer.json schema": {
              "href": "https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#the-composer-json-schema",
              "summary": "This chapter will explain all of the fields available in composer.json."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
$ ~/opt/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh --version
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
PhpStorm 2023.2
Build #PS-232.8660.205
$ php8.2 --version
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2023 07:10:21) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans
$ tree
.
├── _actual-content.php
├── composer.json
├── index.php
└── README.md
```

Comment: Thanks @hakre for your clarification. Aaaand of course now there was a typo in the version # in my earlier comment on the question. Of course it's 2023.1.2 (not 2013.1.2), so it's not THAT old. I have a screenshot of what the tooltip/dropdown looks like for me (totally different, btw). Will add to _another_ answer, as adding to the original q (cannot add img to comment) would completely confuse everything.

Comment: see my 3rd answer just now. I didn't want to put that screenshot in the original answer, I felt that would just add to confusion. So found separate "answer" is  not ideal but better solution.

Comment: re last point: I know, would have, but there's a 2 day embargo on accepting your own answer. :) Will set a reminder.

Comment: All fine @Siv, that's what I mean it is not immediately possible. Ping me here in case things don't work out towards your favour.

Answer (score 1):

I think Occam's Razor applies here, to be brutally honest.

PHPStorm doesn't know how to go back to whatever included the file to get the values, so as far as it knows, that value is undefined. Why you're able to access it via `$GLOBALS` is because it's registered as a global and PHPStorm just indiscriminately applies those to every file in the application.

Now, if you were to be working with classes, it's a bit different.

```
class A 
{
    public $someProperty;
}

class B extends A
{
    public function checkSomeProperty()
    {
        return $this->someProperty;
    }
}
```

Even if each of these classes is in a different file, when you open the file for `class B` in PHPStorm, it will be able to check the lineage of the class and will find `$someProperty` to be part of its lineage.

Hopefully that helps understand the behavior.